# change field names in a list of Objects

Tags: java

I use hql to query from database. first query returns a list of objects like this

see image: [image: Image 1]

as you can see, the field names of retrieved objects are obvious (ID, TIMESTAMP, ...)

but in the second query, what I get, is this:

see image: [image: Image 2]

and I need to change field names ([0] to ID , [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk3a9.jpg) to TITLE, ...)
any solutions?!

Comment: Please include the queries you used to generate the results.

Comment: for the 1st image: I query this:
"from COURTZONE"

and for the second one the query is:
"Select A.ID, A.TITLE, A.PARENT_COURTBRANCH From COURTBRANCH as A"

Comment: One of those queries you're selecting an entity (and thus get a list of the corresponding objets) and on the other you select single attributes and as such get a list of arrays (with the selected objects at their respective position). If you always want object, don't select attributes, but entire objects.

Comment: +1 to Joachim. An please, respect the Java naming conventions. Neither classes nor fields should be in all-uppercase.

Comment: because 2 fields of the second table have many to one relation to other table fields, I should use this query:
`Select A.ADDRESS, A.CODE, A.FAX , A.ID, A.ID_BRANCHTYPE, A.ID_COURTZONE, A.LAYERACCESS," +
                    "A.PARENT_COURTBRANCH, A.STATE, A.TEL, A.TIMESTAMP, A.TITLE, B.TITLE, C.TITLE\n" +
                    "From COURTBRANCH as A , COURTZONE as B, BRANCHTYPE as C \n" +
                    "where B.CODE=A.ID_COURTZONE And A.ID_BRANCHTYPE=C.CODE"`

so I have to query like that

Comment: the original query is this. the query above was just for example

Comment: @JBNizet: yes I know, but the company I work for, have their own rules for naming classes,fields,...

Comment: replace the query by `select A, B.TITLE, C.TITLE from...` and you'll have an instance of COURTBRANCH as the first element of each array.

Comment: thanks JB Nizet, but this one returns this list. what can I do with that? see http://img.majidonline.com/pic/294210/33.JPG

Comment: What's the problem? The first element is a COURTBRANCH instance, the second is the title of B, and the third one is the title of C.

Comment: I'm using kendo treeview, and for binding it, I should produce json data for that. also I should define a field name for datasource as ID,
the first query after converting to json produces this:
[{"ID":"22","TITLE":"Tehran","ID_COURTZONE":"12"},{"ID":"33","TITLE":"Qazvin","ID_COURTZONE":"14"}]
thus I can access the field ID but in the second query the generated json is this:
[["22","Tehran","12"],["33","Qazvin","14"]]
and I still can't have the field name 'ID'

Comment: by the way the query you said select A, B.TITLE, C.TITLE from... has problem, selecting whole A, returns error, because of that relation with other table field (many to one) that was why I selected desired fields
that's the problem.

Comment: How can the queryboth work (since you showed a debugger screenshot of the result of the query) and cause an error? The error is not in the query. The error is somewhere in your code.

Comment: that query select A, B.title, ... doesn't work, because of that relation I mentioned. see http://img.majidonline.com/pic/294337/44.JPG
and this is how I do the many-to-one relation: 
`<many-to-one cascade="none" class="Entities.JMS.COURTZONE" column="CODE" name="refID_COURTZONE" not-null="false" insert="false" update="false"/>
        <many-to-one cascade="none" class="Entities.JMS.BRANCHTYPE" column="CODE" name="refID_BRANCHTYPE" not-null="false" insert="false" update="false"/>`

Comment: also see kendo treeview binding, the section: schema->model->id ( in scripts)
it uses EmployeeId while the query I get doesn't return field name. that's the whole story :) and thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a simple data holding object that contains your needed data.
2. Fill your data into such an object
3. Add this object to a new list/array
4. View the debugger on this list again

Comment: thanks for the reply. I made a list<courtbranch> and then I iterated through my lst (query) this way:
            `List<COURTBRANCH> lstCourtBranchObj = null;
             for(Object obj : lst) {
               lstCourtBranchObj.add((COURTBRANCH) obj);
            }`
it returns error and says can not cast class to object. what should I do?